# How to load json data to DataTable with editable rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

Guys need your expert advise,
I was following this examples on using datatable plugin and was just wondering if its possible to populate a table with actions to edit rows using ajax?

the code I've got so far is this. this code successfully creates the input elements and save links for the datatable but I'm not sure where to put the ajax loading function.

```
(function( $ ) {

'use strict';

var EditableTable = {

    options: {
        addButton: '#addToTable',
        table: '#branches-editable',
        dialog: {
            wrapper: '#dialog',
            cancelButton: '#dialogCancel',
            confirmButton: '#dialogConfirm',
        }
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this
            .setVars()
            .build()
            .loadData()
            .events();
    },

    setVars: function() {
        this.$table             = $( this.options.table );
        this.$addButton         = $( this.options.addButton );

        // dialog
        this.dialog             = {};
        this.dialog.$wrapper    = $( this.options.dialog.wrapper );
        this.dialog.$cancel     = $( this.options.dialog.cancelButton );
        this.dialog.$confirm    = $( this.options.dialog.confirmButton );

        return this;
    },

    build: function() {
        this.datatable = this.$table.DataTable({
            aoColumns: [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { "bSortable": false }
            ]
        });

        window.dt = this.datatable;
        return this;
    },

    // Trying to load my json data here but getting an error saying
    // DataTables warning: table id=branches-editable - 
    // Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, 
    // please see http://datatables.net/tn/3
    loadData: function() {
        this.datatable = this.$table.DataTable({
            bProcessing: true,
            sAjaxSource: this.$table.data('url')
        });
    },

    events: function() {
        var _self = this;

        this.$table
            .on('click', 'a.save-row', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();

                _self.rowSave( $(this).closest( 'tr' ) );
            })
            .on('click', 'a.cancel-row', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();

                _self.rowCancel( $(this).closest( 'tr' ) );
            })
            .on('click', 'a.edit-row', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();

                _self.rowEdit( $(this).closest( 'tr' ) );
            })
            .on( 'click', 'a.remove-row', function( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $row = $(this).closest( 'tr' );

                $.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        src: _self.options.dialog.wrapper,
                        type: 'inline'
                    },
                    preloader: false,
                    modal: true,
                    callbacks: {
                        change: function() {
                            _self.dialog.$confirm.on( 'click', function( e ) {
                                e.preventDefault();

                                _self.rowRemove( $row );
                                $.magnificPopup.close();
                            });
                        },
                        close: function() {
                            _self.dialog.$confirm.off( 'click' );
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        this.$addButton.on( 'click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            _self.rowAdd();
        });

        this.dialog.$cancel.on( 'click', function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.magnificPopup.close();
        });

        return this;
    },

    // ==========================================================================================
    // ROW FUNCTIONS
    // ==========================================================================================
    rowAdd: function() {
        this.$addButton.attr({ 'disabled': 'disabled' });

        var actions,
            data,
            $row;

        actions = [
            '<a href="#" class="hidden on-editing save-row"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></a>',
            '<a href="#" class="hidden on-editing cancel-row"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>',
            '<a href="#" class="on-default edit-row"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>',
            '<a href="#" class="on-default remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>'
        ].join(' ');

        data = this.datatable.row.add([ '', '', '', '', actions ]);
        $row = this.datatable.row( data[0] ).nodes().to$();

        $row
            .addClass( 'adding' )
            .find( 'td:last' )
            .addClass( 'actions' );

        this.rowEdit( $row );

        this.datatable.order([0,'asc']).draw(); // always show fields
    },

    rowCancel: function( $row ) {
        var _self = this,
            $actions,
            i,
            data;

        if ( $row.hasClass('adding') ) {
            this.rowRemove( $row );
        } else {

            data = this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data();
            this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data( data );

            $actions = $row.find('td.actions');
            if ( $actions.get(0) ) {
                this.rowSetActionsDefault( $row );
            }

            this.datatable.draw();
        }
    },

    rowEdit: function( $row ) {
        var _self = this,
            data;

        data = this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data();

        $row.children( 'td' ).each(function( i ) {
            var $this = $( this );

            if ( $this.hasClass('actions') ) {
                _self.rowSetActionsEditing( $row );
            } else {
                $this.html( '<input type="text" class="form-control input-block" value="' + data[i] + '"/>' );
            }
        });
    },

    rowSave: function( $row ) {
        var _self     = this,
            $actions,
            values    = [];

        if ( $row.hasClass( 'adding' ) ) {
            this.$addButton.removeAttr( 'disabled' );
            $row.removeClass( 'adding' );
        }

        values = $row.find('td').map(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            if ( $this.hasClass('actions') ) {
                _self.rowSetActionsDefault( $row );
                return _self.datatable.cell( this ).data();
            } else {
                return $.trim( $this.find('input').val() );
            }
        });

        this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).data( values );

        $actions = $row.find('td.actions');
        if ( $actions.get(0) ) {
            this.rowSetActionsDefault( $row );
        }

        this.datatable.draw();
    },

    rowRemove: function( $row ) {
        if ( $row.hasClass('adding') ) {
            this.$addButton.removeAttr( 'disabled' );
        }

        this.datatable.row( $row.get(0) ).remove().draw();
    },

    rowSetActionsEditing: function( $row ) {
        $row.find( '.on-editing' ).removeClass( 'hidden' );
        $row.find( '.on-default' ).addClass( 'hidden' );
    },

    rowSetActionsDefault: function( $row ) {
        $row.find( '.on-editing' ).addClass( 'hidden' );
        $row.find( '.on-default' ).removeClass( 'hidden' );
    }
};

$(function() {
    EditableTable.initialize();
});

}).apply( this, [ jQuery ]);
```

Comment: Getting proper edit functionality (adding inputs in fields, proper searching of those inputs, syncing the rendered table with the server data, keeping up with changed rows while paging through the data, etc...) is all possible. However, it is non-trivial and far too broad for this site.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir, could you give some advice or is there something wrong with my code? those are in the samples page of their site and I just put them together.

Comment: Hi Richard, for what it's worth, ive left an answer below that should get you on the right track. :)

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from experience, having built what youre asking for before (a Datatables implementation with fully editable rows) I can tell you that the issue you have right now, "Cannot reinitialise DataTable" is only the first of many issues that you are going to run into with this project. It is doable, but there are several issues you will need to resolve that are out of the scope of this question (more about those later).

Your specific issue here is that you are attempting to *reinitialize* your datatable all over again, which as the error states, you cant do. What you can do is [reload](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) the datatable something like `datatable.ajax.reload()` or, if you just want to re-[draw](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) with the current data (to clear changes perhaps) something like `dataTable.rows().invalidate().draw();`

As an example, here are the functions from my own implementation that initialize and redraw my table to avoid the issue you are facing:

```
initDataTable:function(){
    var _this=this;
    if(_this.options.trackRowsWithChanges){
        _this.trackRowsWithChanges();
    }
    if(!_this.dataTable) _this.dataTable=$(_this.options.tableId).DataTable(_this.options.dataTableOptions);
    if(_this.options.useLiveDomSort){
        _this.useLiveDomSort();
    }
    return _this.dataTable;
},

redrawTable:function(fromServer,sortOrder){
    var _this=this;
    fromServer ?  _this.dataTable.ajax.reload() : _this.dataTable.rows().invalidate().draw();
    if(sortOrder) _this.dataTable.order([ 0, 'desc' ],[ 1, 'asc' ]).draw()

}
```

Of course, like I mentioned, there will be other issues, for example:

- Your rows will not be properly searched with the default datables search functionality, you'll have to extend datatables with your own search functions to account for getting the input values instead of column text.
- Youll need to track changes on the internal datatables data and not just in the visible ui because of paging. Change a value on the first page, then move the the second page, then move back and your changes will be gone because datatables only draws the current "page" of rows in the UI and they are destroyed and re-created when changing pages.
- Adding new rows is.....problematic and you DO NOT want to hard code it the way you started, make it dynamically add them based the actual data, trust me youll thank me when you go to use this code for a different datatable ;)
- Making newly added rows always be added at the top of the table where you can see it (and not on like the middle of the last hidden page) is not trivial youll need to precisely control sorting for this to work right
- Tabbing between cells and landing in the inputs as you would expect is not supported properly by default, youll need to write some shims to make that work, but do it as your users will expect that to work

I cant easily make you a working example ( id have to make a database and set all that up) But, if you are interested, let me know and Ill share my full implementation with you as files.

Comment: It might be useful to check out [x-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/), I managed to integrate it to datatables and it worked out pretty well. The columns where fully editable.

Comment: @Sebastianb interesting, how does that plugin deal with the paging issue I mentioned above? How do you handle adding rows?

Comment: Well, the plugin gets re-initialized in every draw (using fnDrawCallback) on the specific `tr`'s, so this alone makes adding/removing rows easier (`tabla.row.add(data).draw()` is enough, same for remove), and regarding pagination, I guess the drawCallback and the fact that the plugin also changes the content of the DOM makes it all work.

Comment: mind you, it's been a while so there might be a bit of code lurking somewhere that I didn't manage to catch right now ;)

Comment: oh and the filter/search functionality keeps working because x-editable doesn't change the content of the cell until you click/double-click. Just Then, the DOM gets updated and an input field shows up.